# How can a lightweight weak girl overcome a weighty man pushing her down on the floor?

Tags: groundwork

Consider [1:30](https://youtu.be/6CE-lPakRVM?t=90). Let me know if you have another better video of this martial art falling technique. But pretend

1. that white shirt **sturdy, weighty** man  attacks me ***wickedly and spitefully***.
2. and that underdog lad is an INNOCENT, DEFENSELESS, POWERLESS featherweight. I'm actually a girl by the way.

As you can see, that hefty weighty man looks forceful. He pushes that stripling to the ground and pins him down on the ground. How can that underdog lad defend and overwhelm the strapping attacker?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a question that can be exhaustively answered in a stackexchange answer.

Short version 1: the first step would probably be for the person on the bottom to frame with their arms on the attacker's neck to take away some of the pressure, and avoid getting choked out. Next, the person on the bottom either needs to turn on their side toward the guy on top, and get to their knees and stand up; or turn their hips toward the attacker and use their legs to create space and control the attacker, then scoot away and get up. Actually doing either requires...

Short version 2: go to a BJJ, MMA or Judo school, learn the basics of groundwork, and focus on training escapes. Nothing anyone can write will help you much unless you've done this plenty of times in training. Escape techniques and strategies exist. Whether they work in a given situation is a matter of practice, size, strength, determination, and conditioning. Bad situations are bad, no matter what.